# Hudson / default Maven

Tags: maven-2, hudson

i cannot figure out how to set a default maven. Within a job configuration if you add a Maven Build you have to specify a Version and the goal. The first item in the select box for version is "default". If you have specified other versions under "configure hudson" they will appear there too. However i want all my jobs to use the default. Do i have to set some kind of envoirment variable so hudson knows which maven version is the default one?

Thanks,

kuku

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `MAVEN_HOME` and adding `${MAVEN_HOME}/bin` to your executable `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I don't have the default option for maven. So either you have a different Hudson version (I run 1.376) or HUdson recognizes that you have set up maven on the command prompt. In this case the maven installation might not be complete/correct for the user Hudson is running under.

If that doesn't help, let us know what OS you are running on.

Comment: i have a older version indeed i will check tomorrow which version it is. If i try to use the default one hudson looks for the mvn.bat in the current job's folder.